# Wildcard equivalent in C# generics

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, wildcard

Let's say I have a generic class as follows:

```
public class GeneralPropertyMap<T>
{
}
```

In some other class I have a method that takes in an array of `GeneralPropertyMap<T>`. In Java, in order to take in an array that contains any type of `GeneralPropertyMap` the method would look like this:

```
private void TakeGeneralPropertyMap(GeneralPropertyMap<?>[] maps)
{
}
```

We use the wildcard so that later we can call `TakeGeneralPropertyMap` passing a bunch of `GeneralPropertyMap` with any type for `T` each, like this:

```
GeneralPropertyMap<?>[] maps = new GeneralPropertyMap<?>[3];
maps[0] = new GeneralPropertyMap<String>();
maps[1] = new GeneralPropertyMap<Integer>();
maps[2] = new GeneralPropertyMap<Double>();
//And finally pass the array in.
TakeGeneralPropertyMap(maps);
```

I'm trying to figure out an equivalent in C# with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried making the function take `GeneralPropertyMap<object>[] maps` .. I guess it should work because of Covariance

Answer (score 24):

Generics in C# make stronger guarantees than generics in Java. Therefore, to do what you want in C#, you have to let the `GeneralPropertyMap<T>` class inherit from a non-generic version of that class (or interface).

```
public class GeneralPropertyMap<T> : GeneralPropertyMap
{
}

public class GeneralPropertyMap
{
    // Only you can implement it:
    internal GeneralPropertyMap() { }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
private void TakeGeneralPropertyMap(GeneralPropertyMap[] maps)
{
}
```

And:

```
GeneralPropertyMap[] maps = new GeneralPropertyMap[3];
maps[0] = new GeneralPropertyMap<String>();
maps[1] = new GeneralPropertyMap<Integer>();
maps[2] = new GeneralPropertyMap<Double>();
TakeGeneralPropertyMap(maps);
```

Comment: It's still not good enough since in the interface you will most likely want to have a method that returns or takes a wildcard to use from the "TakeGeneralPropertyMap" method, which you can't do because we don't want the interface to be of a generic type. However, this answer at least gets close. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 12):

While, as others have noted, there's no exact correspondence to wildcards in c#, some of their use cases can be covered with [covariance/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

```
public interface IGeneralPropertyMap<out T> {} // a class can't be covariant, so 
                                        // we need to introduce an interface...

public class GeneralPropertyMap<T> : IGeneralPropertyMap<T> {} // .. and have our class
                                                            // inherit from it

//now our method becomes something like
private void TakeGeneralPropertyMap<T>(IList<IGeneralPropertyMap<T>> maps){}

// and you can do
    var maps = new List<IGeneralPropertyMap<Object>> {
        new GeneralPropertyMap<String>(),
        new GeneralPropertyMap<Regex>()
    };
    //And finally pass the array in.
    TakeGeneralPropertyMap<Object>(maps);
```

The caveat is that you can't use covariance with value types, so adding a new `GeneralPropertyMap<int>()` to our list fails at compile time.

```
cannot convert from 'GeneralPropertyMap<int>' to 'IGeneralPropertyMap<object>'
```

This approach may be more convenient than having a non-generic version of your classes/interfaces in case you want to constrain the types that `GeneralPropertyMap` can contain. In that case:

```
public interface IMyType {}
public class A : IMyType {}
public class B : IMyType {}
public class C : IMyType {}

public interface IGeneralPropertyMap<out T> where T : IMyType {}
```

allows you to have:

```
var maps = new List<IGeneralPropertyMap<IMyType>> {
    new GeneralPropertyMap<A>(),
    new GeneralPropertyMap<B>() ,
    new GeneralPropertyMap<C>() 
};
TakeGeneralPropertyMap(maps);
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct equivalent to this in C#.

In C#, this would often be done by having your generic class implement a non-generic interface or base class:

```
interface IPropertyMap
{
   // Shared properties
}

public class GeneralPropertyMap<T> : IPropertyMap
{
}
```

You could then pass an array of these:

```
IPropertyMap[] maps = new IPropertyMap[3];
// ...

TakePropertyMap(maps);
```

Comment: I understand the Generic methods, but they won't do in this case. Every time I call it, I can only specify one type for the GeneralPropertyMap. So I can only call it passing either an array of GeneralPropertyMap<string>[], or GeneralPropertyMap<double>, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface from the members of `GeneralPropertyMap` (`IGeneralPropertyMap`), and then take an `IGeneralPropertyMap[]` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can get pretty close to a wildcard by using dynamic. This also works nicely if you have a non-generic superclass.

For example:

```
public class A
{
  // ...
}

public class B<T> : A
{
  // ...
}

public class Program
{
  public static A MakeA() { return new A(); }

  public static A MakeB() { return new B<string>(); }

  public static void Visit<T>(B<T> b)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("This is B with type "+typeof(T).FullName);
  }

  public static void Visit(A a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("This is A");
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    A instA = MakeA();
    A instB = MakeB();

    // This calls the appropriate methods.
    Visit((dynamic)instA);
    Visit((dynamic)instB);

    // This calls Visit(A a) twice.
    Visit(instA);
    Visit(instB);
  }
}
```

How this works is explained in the C# documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic#overload-resolution-with-arguments-of-type-dynamic).