# c# cannot cast from 'IInterface<IOtherInterface>' to 'IInterface - Convert class without generic to interface with generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I Have the interface `IJob` which is an parameter in many of my functions. But this interface is actually generic (`IJob<T>`). I want to avoid passing the generic Parameter around to all functions. So i did something like the following:

```cs
public interface ISomeType
{
    string X { get; set; }
}
public interface IJob<T>
where T : ISomeType
{
    string SomeProp { get; set; }
    T GenericProp { get; set; }
}
public interface IJob : IJob<ISomeType> { }

public class Job<T> : IJob<T>
where T : ISomeType
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    public T GenericProp { get; set; }
}
public class Job : Job<ISomeType> { }

public class SomeOtherType : ISomeType
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

So my functions now look like this:

```cs
public void DoSomething(IJob job){}
//instead of:
public void DoSomething<T>(IJob<T> job)
where T:ISomeType {}
```

I Want to do that beacause those functions never touch `GenericProp` - they only need to know that `T` is `ISomeType`

Everything works fine, but i came to a point where the following will not work:
I want to store all Jobs in a `IDictionary<string,IJob> jobs` and i don´t know the type of `GenericProp` before runtime. So i need to cast a `Job<T>` to `IJob` in order to add it to the Dictionary, but this throws an casting Error.

```cs
IJob job = (IJob)new Job<SomeOtherType>();
```

In general i don´t feel like my solution is a best-practice. But how do I work with polymorphic classes instead?

Comment: Hi, perhaps use inheritance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574977/wildcard-equivalent-in-c-sharp-generics

Comment: thanks for your awnser @IronMan! Could you please explain a bit more specific which approach i should use? I can´t  use covariance

Comment: maybe have the generic extend a non-generic interface?

Comment: this also won´t work. Because i will have to hide `ISomeType GenericProp {get;set,}` with the new keyword like this: `new T GenericProp {get;set,}`. Because of that i will lose the reference to GenericProp if i cast from `IJob<T>` to `IJob`